# jquery mobile data-transition slide not working when page is too long

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Currently, I'm using jquery mobile `data-transition="slide"`.

It is working when page content is not so long, it means roughly less than 1400px(the page height), it works perfectly.

However when page content is too long, slide effects does not work, link is still living but no slide effect.

I tested manytimes and I'm sure that error occurs depends on page length.
Please please help me out of this problem.

Comment: If you paste your code here it's more likely somebody will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour might be related to [`$.mobile.getMaxScrollForTransition`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/#getMaxScrollForTransition).

If your scroll position is further than this threshold (e.g. on long pages), all custom page transitions are ignored and the transition defaults to `none`.

The default value for `$.mobile.getMaxScrollForTransition` is three times the page height so you have to scroll quite a bit for the effect to kick in.